# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <> in jQuery in a Backbone/Marionette app

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I ran into a cryptic error message from deep in the bowels of jQuery code.

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <>
```

I'm sure the problem has nothing to do with jQuery itself. It's somewhere in my application, which is built in Backbone + Marionette.

I had to wade through hundreds of lines of code, but this test case demonstrates the problem in its simplest possible form. (You can go to the [Mariontte.js web site](http://marionettejs.com/) and type this code in the JavaScript console.

```js
var V = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({tagName: ''});
v = new V();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This begs the question: what were you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm getting spoiled by being able to find a solution to most of my problems within 5 minutes by just Googling the error message. Didn't work this time, so I figured I'd ask / answer my own question in hope of helping the next person.

Comment: That make sense. I was just curious about your purpose for specifying a blank "tagName". Maybe someone else has that same goal. Did you end up not using a blank string?

Comment: The reason was a very overworked coworker who hasn't had enough sleep. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the empty tag name.

```js
tagName: ''
```

There's some code in Marionette or Backbone that that basically does this:

```js
jQuery('<' + tagName + '>')
```

So that an empty `tagName` causes jQuery to be called with `<>`, which is a meaningless expression. The `tagName` on [CollectionView](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.2/marionette.collectionview.html) (or any [View](http://backbonejs.org/#View)) is optional, but has to be an actual HTML tag. It can't be the emtpy string.